# Clicking and turn signal blinking after disconnecting battery

Tags: subaru, outback

I disconnected my battery to change my spark plugs today.  With everything reconnected, the engine runs fine.  Afterwards, the car produces a clicking noise at about 1 Hz for periods of several seconds.  The clicking noise is coordinated with the radio backlight flashing and the turn signals blinking too.  I'm worried this will drain the battery.

What did I mess up?

I tried manipulating all driver-side controls and buttons but didn't find anything that would stop the ticking.

Here's a video, if it helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLxIgL4OBXQ

Thanks!

1998 Subaru Outback (2.5L).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be the "security system:" https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/Discussion-t17156_ds520375

Turning the key to the ON position in the ignition before reconnecting the ground solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Subaru.  But it sounds like you got a bad ground wire. Since you disconnected the battery I would look in that area. Look for any wires that are grounded to the fender, broken wires. Or just plain loose wire. Hope this helps

Comment: Ground wire seems fine.  Engine starts, lights work, etc.